Continuity of the sum of continuous functions on a topological vector space
Suppose that $V$ is a topological vector space, and $f$ and $g$ are two continuous functions on $V$ $(f,g: V\rightarrow V)$. My question is, is $f+g$ a continuous function? Take $a\in K$, is the function $af$ on $V$ continuous?
A norm structure is not assumed on $V$.

What have you tried?

This is true by definition

Yes, they are both continuous: the maps $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ and $x\mapsto ax$ are continuous by definition of TVS, so in the first case you can just compose the (continuous) map $(f,g)\colon V\times V\rightarrow V\times V$ with the addition map, and the second case is analogous.
